# Do I need a login table?

Tags: sql, database

Hey guys I have a simple database question. Say I am emulating a university login system.

If i have a student table and faculty table, can I just store the password directly in the corresponding table? For example student table has such attributes as (student_ID - primary key), First_name, Last_name, Classification, and now I would add a password field.

If I create a login table i'm just effectively copying over thousands of potential records. Is there any benefit to creating a login table with say (primary key STUDENT_ID,FACULTY_ID) and a password field for authentication purposes?

Can I increase security on just one table? What is the better approach?

Comment: The student will only have one password so it will be safe to store the password in the student table. You will most probably use the email address or username that will reside in that table as well. Keep you data normailzed as far as possible. It is not necessary to duplicate student id's in a new table. Also store encrypt the password and create a lost password to reset the password for the user. That way the system does not know what the password is, only the user.

Comment: if you do so, how will you generalize the query?? If a faculty logs in, u have to query the faculty table and student table for student respectively!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one student contains only one password, there maintains `one to one relationship` so there is no need of splitting the table for one to one relationship.

If there is one to many relation, breaking the table will be good such as for storing multiple phone numbers or multiple address of a user.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide upon whether only students will be allowed to login into your system.
What about admin user, teachers, etc?

even if there is a remote possibility that a non student will log into the system it is advisable to create a login table with userid and password stored in MD5 encryption